# Replace nested query to get latest related row

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query to get all penalty data with latest prices. In prices table there are many prices related to a product. To take the valid price I need to get the latest price. Here is the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN product_price productPrice
          ON product.id = productPrice.product_id
          AND productPrice.valid_from =
               (SELECT valid_from FROM product_price
                WHERE product_price.is_active = true AND valid_from <= now()
                ORDER BY valid_from DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE product.id = 1;
```

My question: Is there any way to replace the nested query here in order to take only one latest date from the product_price table or is it ok to use nested queries.

Comment: Do you have a problem? If not, then it is Ok to use this construction. Please check the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` for your SQL statement.

Comment: Using nested queries does it affects to the performance of the query

Comment: Every piece of SQL affects the performance. Sometimes it improves performance, sometimes it makes things worse. That's why you check the query plan. Do you have a performance problem?

Comment: *is it ok to use nested queries* - yes, SQL is declarative, you are not usually concerned with the *how*, you let the optimizer work out the best way to execute a query. If you have a performance problem, that's a different question.

Comment: So is there any other way to do the same thing in this scenario as you think. Or this way better?

Comment: @FrankHeikens No I don't have that much performance problem. I just want to know any other way to do the same thing rather using nested query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve data for a single given product, a `LATERAL` subquery is typically fastest. Most flexible, too.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   product p
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   product_price pp
   WHERE  pp.product_id = p.id
   AND    pp.is_active
   AND    pp.valid_from <= now()
   ORDER  BY pp.valid_from DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) ON true
WHERE  p.id = 1;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Be sure to have an **index** on `product_price (product_id, valid_from)`, or some refined version, depending on undisclosed details. A PK index on `product(id)` can be assumed.

Retrieving most or all products at once is typically faster with a different query style. But your given query clearly indicates a single product.

#### Subtle differences

Your original returns **all** related rows from `product_price` with the latest `valid_from`. My query always picks a single one. Typically, `(product_id, valid_from)` should be defined `UNIQUE` to make this unambiguous.

Your original also returns **no row** from `product_price` where any related row with `valid_from IS NULL` exists. Null sorts on top in descending sort order and the subsequent join condition `valid_from = null` eliminates all rows. You would have a `NOT NULL` constraint or at least use `DESC NULLS LAST` in the query to sort null values last. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

(And you should declare all of that in the question.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` to keep the first row of each group. For example, you can do:

```
select distinct on (p.id) *
from product p
left join product_price pp on p.id = pp.product_id  
  and pp.valid_from <= now() and pp.is_active = true
where p.id = 1 
order by p.id, pp.valid_from desc
```